# Table view cell heights using Autolayout disappear after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` for a feed where I would like the height of the table view cells to vary depending on whether there is a picture and also the size of the picture.

Following this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/) and many questions on SO, I have placed autolayout constraints on the custom cell elements to the `ContentView` and, in turn, I have put the following two lines in `viewDidLoad`.

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

From what I have read, this is supposed to manage the cell heights.

The good news is the table view displays correctly on load. The cells with pictures are tall and show the pictures. The cells without pictures are short and do not show pictures.

The bad news is that as I scroll downward, cells that should not have images have images.  The pattern is  two cells with images followed by two cells without images where all the cells should not have images.

I'm thinking the problem has something to do with dequeuing and then requeuing the cells but supposedly all you need to do is put the above two lines in `viewDidLoad`.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

**Edit**:

This is my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which takes a custom cell `Cell`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    IDFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[IDFeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                        reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    Feed *aFeed = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell withFeed:aFeed];

    return cell;
}
```

The code for configure cell is very elaborate as there are ten elements.  However, for the image view in question a simplified version that still has the issue is follows:

```
- (void)configureCell:(IDFeedCell *)cell withFeed: (Feed *)feed {
    if (feed.itempic.length <= 3) {
        cell.messageImage = nil;
        cell.messageImage.hidden= YES;
    } else {
        cell.messageImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zocrates.png"];//placeholder for dynamic images.
        cell.messageImage.hidden= NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's undoubtedly how you implemented your `cellForRowAt` method and/or how you're updating the image view. But we can't help you without a [simple yet reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. The problem is not in auto-layout or in auto-dimensioned cells, but rather how you're updating your cells, and there's simply not enough here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: See edit.  My code in configure cell was very complicated.  It involved downloading images from the web storing them in core data and so forth.  Simplifying the code to the above has changed the problem slightly to first screen loads correctly but when you scroll down,images now show up when they should not.  But gist of problem seems to be same, images not getting queued and requeued properly.

Comment: Your code snippet unfortunately raises more questions than it raises. If we're going to help you, we need that [minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, make copy of project and rip out everything unrelated to this bug until you're down to the absolutely bare minimum required to reproduce the bug. Or, probably better, go the other way and start blank project and add minimal stuff to manifest the bug. But unless you're going to hire someone to go through this, you need to simplify this.

Comment: Completely unrelated, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (unlike `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`) always returns a value. There's no need to check for `nil`. That's a very old pattern, largely rendered obsolete many years ago...

Comment: If you are telling me there is no error in the above code (other than the unnecessary checking for nil), that is helpful.  I will look for the issue elsewhere.

Comment: I removed the constraints and the issue went away so there does not appear to be anything wrong with cellforrowatindexpath in the absence of constraints.  However, with the constraints present, the images are not getting cleaned out when the cells are dequeued and recycled for some reason.